# Primefaces lazy datatable: put my own filter instead of GlobalFilter

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

I d like to add some extra filters on my Lazy Data Table but these fields are not based on the fields I have (actually my filter would be dateFrom and dateTo and I only have a field "Date").

I'd like to have two extra filter fields on the top of my datatable instead of a global filter:

```
    <f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
    <p:inputText id="globalFilterOther" onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()" style="display:inlineblock;"/>
    <p:inputText id="globalFilterAnOtherFilter" onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()" style="display:inlineblock;"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
```

The problem is that as soon as I change id into something else than global Filter, no filter is detected. How could I do?

Comment: Like you normally would create anything that filters things. Bind the inputs to a field in a backingbean via their `value` attributes and method that does the actual filtering (in this case the load method in the lazyDataModel) access the fields in that bean an use them in your technical filtering...

Comment: @Kukeltje that will work. Binding the fields to a `Map` and adding that map to the filters in the filter listener is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is binding the two (or more) extra filter fields to a `Map<String,String>`. For example add a map called `filters` to your bean:

```
private Map<String,String> filters = new HashMap<>();
// Include getter and setter
```

... and bind the filters to properties of the map:

```
<p:inputText value="#{myBean['field']}"
             onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()"/>
<p:inputText value="#{myBean['otherField']}"
             onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()"/>
```

Now, the only thing you need to do is adding a filter listener to the `p:dataTable`, and there add the `filters` map to the event filters and you are done.

Bean:

```
public void onFilter(FilterEvent event){
  event.getFilters().putAll(filters);
}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
  <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{myBean.onFilter}"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: I'll see if I can enhance this answer to become a full example.  I've seen beginners struggle with the combining of the lazydatamodel and the additional filters. I used a producer method for the filters and have the filters (indeed in a map with the exception of the multi-tenant one)