# Primefaces datatable filter specific column in header

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

In Primefaces datatable, it can filter a specific column by the following code:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{car.id}" headerText="Id" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
</p:column>
```

The code above will generate a filter on the header of the column. What I want is create a filter on the header of datatable, not column. From the [ShowCase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml), there is a code:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>
```

This will put a filter in header of datatable, but it will filter the all fields of the datatable, which is what I don't want, I want it to filter specific column only, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could by using a few hacks. First add a `widgetVar` attribute to your `p:dataTable`, for example `widgetVar="myTable"`. Then, add an `id` attribute to you `p:column`:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{car.id}"
          headerText="Id"
          filterMatchMode="contains"
          id="clm">
  <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
</p:column>
```

You can use this id to select the column filter field. In the global filter, you want to remove the `id` attribute, and add an `onkeyup` listener which sets the input's value in the column's filter and triggers filtering on the table using the `widgetVar`.

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <p:inputText onkeyup="document.getElementById('frm:tbl:clm:filter').value=this.value; PF('myTable').filter();"/>
</f:facet>
```

Here I assume your form has the ID `frm` and your data table has the ID `tbl`. They probably have different IDs, so change the code accordingly.

If you don't want the filter to be visible in the column, you could hide it with a CSS rule:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-column-filter[id='frm:tbl:clm:filter'] {
  display: none;
}
```

If you are using lazy loading you could also check out [Primefaces lazy datatable: put my own filter instead of GlobalFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304057/primefaces-lazy-datatable-put-my-own-filter-instead-of-globalfilter)